# Is there a way to start/stop oracle 12c with bat file?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Is there a way to start oracle 12c with bat file ? like it used to be in 11g.

How can i start and stop all oracle 12c operations that would be easier to manage resources when you are on limited resources on pc/mac.

Answer (score 3):

As you mention a "bat" file, I assume you are talking about Windows.

Oracle installs two Windows services: the listener and the database instance. Typically they are called `OracleOraDB12Home1TNSListener` for the listener and `OracleServiceORCL` for the instance.

Especially the name of the service for the instance may be different depending on the SID you chose during installation.

Just set those two services to "manual" (**not** "automatic") then they won't be started when Windows start.

To start Oracle later, create a .bat file with the following commands:

```
net start OracleOraDB12Home1TNSListener
net start OracleServiceORCL
```

You have to adjust the names of the services to your installation. Check the "Services" app in the control panel

To stop the Oracle services, just use `stop` instead of `start`

Comment: Thanks man . Don't know why people negative vote  instead of encouraging people ,they don't use brains to help others. pathetic people.pfff